# MySQLI bind params using call_user_func_array not working

Tags: php, mysqli, bind

Why its not working? I am trying to dynamically bind params based on what user send GET data. Not sure what is wrong about it.

```
    $bind_param = array();
    $array_param = array();
    $params = array();
    $i = 0;
    $bind_param[$i] = "i";
    $array_param[$i] = $_GET['p2'];

    $query = "SELECT * from point where fixture_id = ? ";

    if(isset($_GET['p1'])){
        $query .= "and user_id = ? ";
        $i++;
        $bind_param[$i] = "i";
        $array_param[$i] = $_GET['p1'];
    }

    $param_type = '';
    $n = count($bind_param);
    for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
      $param_type .= $bind_param[$i];
    }

    $params[] = $param_type;
    for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
      $params[] = $array_param[$i];
    }

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);

    $stmt->execute();
```

Error :

```
PHP Warning:  Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting references into the array instead of values (notice the ampersands):

```
$params[] = &$param_type;
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
  $params[] = &$array_param[$i];
}
```

Comment: wow. i just missed out the `&` symbol. i never know what is the use of `&` to be put at the front of array variable.

Comment: @ggDeGreat You can read more about references in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php). If this has answered your question, please mark it as accepted.